# how to populate accounts in picklists and display contacts in table based on the selection of the account?(using bootstrap instead of vf)

Tags: apex, bootstrap

**I have tried it using vf but i' m not able to get using bootstrap page.Please kindly help me.**

Comment: Hi Srikanth, your question does not provide enough detail about specific area of problem instead, it is a direct ask which you want from us. Like building code for you. If you could show some effort, a hint of research done before asking question then you have better chances of getting answer else, this question will be closed. Please go through [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy to do, First create a selectoption list in Apex controller side with the accounts, as below

```
public list<selectoption> accountOptionList {get; set;}
public string selectedAccountId {get; set;}
public list<contact> selectAccountContacts;
...
for(account acct: [select id, name from Account]){
     accountOptionList.add(new selectoption(acct.id,acct.name));
}
```

Now in visual-force as you want to try with Bootstrap styling so use the VF tags with Bootstrap styling classes, like:

```
<apex:selectList styleclass="form-control" value="{!selectedAccountId}" multiselect="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!accountOptionList}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

see bootstrap styles here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects

On selection of account you want to render the contacts, so add action support functionality with apex select-list, like below:

```
    <apex:selectList styleclass="form-control" value="{!selectedAccountId}" multiselect="false" size="1">
        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getselectAccountContacts}" reRender="ContactsPanel"/>
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!accountOptionList}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
```

now add one more controller method which retrieve the contacts for selected account, as follows:

```
public list<contact> getselectAccountContacts(){
   return [SELECT id, name, ... FROM Contact WHERE AccountId :selectedAccountId];
}
```

now re-render the contacts on VF page: (As you want to use bootstrap so add bootstrap table styling):

```
<apex:outputPanel id="ContactsPanel">
   <table class="table table-bordered">
     ...
     <apex:repeat value="{!selectAccountContacts}" var="contactRec">
        <tr>
          <td>{!contactRec.name}<td>
          ...
          ...
        </tr>    
     </apex:repeat>
   </table>
</apex:outoputPanel>
```

You can also achieve the same table with `<apex:dataTable>` tag also, in that tag you need to provide bootstrap styling with `styleClass` attribute.

**In case if your Visial-force Page not rendering bootstrap styling properly then just add one attribute `[standardStylesheets = "false"]` in your `<apex:page>` tag, like below:**

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false">
```